# python get amount of odd and even digits

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, dictionary

I need a Python 2.7 function that takes an integes as input and returns dictionary with count of odd and even digits, like so:

```
count_digits(34567)
```

should return `{'odd': 3, 'even': 2}`

Here is my code:

```
def count_digits(num):
  if type(num) == int:
    arr = list(str(num))

    result = {
      'odd': 0,
      'even': 0

    }

    for digit in arr:
      if digit % 2 == 0:
        result['odd'] += 1
      else:
        result['even'] += 1

    return result
  else:
    return False

print count_digits(123)
```

I get an `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: OK. What's stopping you from writing one?

Comment: Can you please show us your attempt? We can help if you get stuck, but will not write the entire code for you.

Comment: Please see the tutorial on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: The mistake is that you must change from: `if digit % 2 == 0:` to `if int(digit) % 2 == 0:` since "arr" is a list of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`digit` in your code is referencing a string not an integer, you shouldn't do `digit % 2`, however, you can use `int(digit)%2`. And when `int(digit)%2==0`, it means `digit` is `even` not `odd`, `odd` is otherwise:

```
def count_digits(num):
  if type(num) == int:
    arr = str(num)

    result = {
      'odd': 0,
      'even': 0

    }

    for digit in arr:
      if int(digit) % 2 == 0:
        result['even'] += 1
      else:
        result['odd'] += 1

    return result
  else:
    return False

print count_digits(123) # => {'odd': 2, 'even': 1}
print count_digits(34567) # => {'odd': 3, 'even': 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to this is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is a subclass of a `dict`

```
from collections import Counter

def count_digits(num):
    return Counter('odd' if int(d) % 2 else 'even' for d in str(num))

print count_digits(123)  
print count_digits(34567)

>>> Counter({'odd': 2, 'even': 1})
>>> Counter({'odd': 3, 'even': 2})
```